# How to reinstall apt-get?

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management

I accidentally ended up deleting `apt-get` from my system (It's an 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 Server). I decided that I would just re-download it from [here.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/apt) However, when I tried to install it by issuing the following command, this happened:

`dpkg -i apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.17_amd64.deb`

```
Preparing to unpack apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.17_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apt (1.0.1ubuntu2.17) over (1.0.1ubuntu2.17) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apt:
apt depends on libapt-pkg4.12 (>= 0.9.16); however:
Version of libapt-pkg4.12:amd64 on system is 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.21.
libapt-pkg5.0:amd64 (1.6~alpha5) breaks apt (<< 1.1~exp14) and is installed.
Version of apt to be configured is 1.0.1ubuntu2.17.

dpkg: error processing package apt (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt
```

I'm not certain how to proceed, could anyone give me some help? Thanks.

Comment: you need a newer version of `libapt-pkg4.12` which was also available in the link you provided, then gracefully force remove apt in dpkg use `dpkg --remove apt`, then first install `libapt-pkg4.12` https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libapt-pkg4.12 then you can proceed now to install apt.

Comment: So I first remove `apt` by typing `dpkg --remove apt` and then I install `libapt-pkg4.12`. After that, I then install apt. Is this correct?

Comment: `apt-get` deals with dependencies, `dpkg` can't.  Hence with `dpkg` you need to install the required 'depends' first, or at the same time.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: I found a file called `libapt-pkg5.0`. I'm not sure if I should remove this though.

Comment: @guiverc thanks for pointing that out i totally overlooked it, @ssharma you just have to put it like this after removing apt `dpkg -i apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.17_amd64.deb libapt-pkg4.12_amd64.deb` this will install it at the same time.

Comment: Ok I'll try that.

Comment: I still received an error.

Comment: I think my error is because I have this file, `libapt-pkg5.0` installed. I think this is a different version. I've tried to remove it, but it seems to have dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured out the problem.

Essentially, I was installing an older version of `apt` (like the idiot I am). Basically, I had the apt library file `libapt-pkg5.0`. This library file corresponds to the `.deb` file found [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/apt/download). Once you download that file (with `wget` or your browser), then you can install it with `dpkg -i apt_1.2.15ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb`. Once that happens, then you're all good to go.

Thanks to the people who attempted to help me.